# Reactjs - array map keeping old array instead of replacing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

im facing this issue where i have two arrays, and it should map through one of the arrays on page navigation. but its keeping the old array and adding the new one instead of replacing the old array with the new one.

array:

```
const array = [
 {
     title: 'itme 1',
     category: 'summer',
 },
 {
     title: 'item 2',
     category: 'summer',
 },
 {
     title: 'item 3',
     category: 'summer',
 },
 {
     title: 'item 4',
     category: 'summer',
 },
 {
     title: 'item 5',
     category: 'summer',
 },
 {
     title: 'item 6',
     category: 'winter',
 },
 {
     title: 'item 7',
     category: 'winter',
 },
 {
     title: 'item 8',
     category: 'winter',
 },
 {
     title: 'item 9',
     category: 'winter',
 },
 {
     title: 'item 10',
     category: 'winter',
 },
]

export default array
```

listPage:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import array from './array'

function page1() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const matchName = router.query.name

 const itemsArray = array.filter(array => array.category === matchName)
 const [listItems, setListItems] = useState(itemsArray.slice(0, 3))

 useEffect(() => {
    setListItems(itemsArray.slice(0, 3))
 }, [ProductMatch])

 return (
   <>
     listItems.map(listItems => <p>listItems</p>)
   </>
 )
}
```

the output of `console.log(itemsArray)` and `console.log(listItems)` is correct and i get the item based on the filter criteria if the url changes. but `listItems.map()` keeps the old filter criteria items and adds the new items. so the list ends up having 'summer' and 'winter' items together.

**current output:**

from mysite.com/name/summer

```
<p>item 1</p>
<p>item 2</p>
<p>item 3</p>
<p>item 4</p>
<p>item 5</p>
```

to mysite.com/name/winter

```
<p>item 1</p>
<p>item 2</p>
<p>item 3</p>
<p>item 4</p>
<p>item 5</p>
<p>item 6</p>
<p>item 7</p>
<p>item 8</p>
<p>item 9</p>
<p>item 10</p>
```

**desired output:**

from mysite.com/name/summer

```
<p>item 1</p>
<p>item 2</p>
<p>item 3</p>
<p>item 4</p>
<p>item 5</p>
```

to mysite.com/name/winter

```
<p>item 6</p>
<p>item 7</p>
<p>item 8</p>
<p>item 9</p>
<p>item 10</p>
```

Comment: 1. Use the array in a parent component as initial state 2. pass the (filtered copy of the) state array down to all components that need it 3. change only the one state array, potentially by passing functions to change it down to children, too

Comment: @ChrisG hi, i didnt understand your comment.  but i added extra details to the question to better illustrate the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to add `key` prop to your JSX?

```js
   listItems.map(listItems => <p key={listItems.title}>listItems</p>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "array" as a parameter for the filter function as you're colliding the original "array" array with it. you should use the form:

```
 const itemsArray = array.filter(item => item.category === matchName)
```